# Beginner Python Area of a room

Tags: python

Right now I am working on a program to calculate the area of a room in order to purchase cans of paint. I am just a three weeks into my class and I'm a little overwhelmed. I'm having trouble figuring out how I am supposed to attach each wall/ceiling/window/door to a separate name such as 'WALL1 WALL2' etc and then being able to call those to a calculation. As far as I have gotten I can't seem to figure out how to write this variable. I am by no means asking for the code to the whole program, so we will take a look at just walls as an example. "John wants to calculate how much paint he needs for a whole house and has 57 walls with various sizes of each wall." How do I allow an unlimited amount of walls to be used while attaching each wall to its Length and Height? Or should I limit the amount of walls? Once I establish how many of these walls there are how do I attach each wall to its own name? Each 'name' will then be called into the final calculation. Here is what I have so far:

```
# Area calculation for paint program
print "Area Calculation For Paint"

Project_Name = input('Enter your Project Name:')

print "WALL1."
print "WALL2."
print "WALL3."
print "WALL4."
print "WALL5"
print "WALL6"
print "WALL7"
print "WALL8"....


# Get the user’s choice:
shape = input("Please select a Wall and input the length and height: ")




# Calculate the area for each room
if WALL1 == yes:
height = input("Please enter the height: ")
length = input("Please enter the length: ")
area1 = height*length
WALL1 = area1



# Calculate the total square footage
TOTALSQFT = WALL1 + WALL2 + WALL3 + WALL4 + WALL5 + CEILING1 - WINDOW1 + WINDOW2 + WINDOW3 + DOOR1 + DOOR2... etc


print "Project_Name total square footage is TOTALSQFT"
```

I have provided my [Flowchart here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca5D8.png) as reference so hopefully it makes better sense what I am trying to explain.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a loop. I suggest having a look at your textbook.

Comment: And I strongly recommend you using `class` if you are allowed to.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 funny thing is my textbook is for my 'Foundations of Software Design' and doesn't cover Python at all. I'll look for information on loops.

Comment: @Arman I have no idea what class is but I will look into it.

Comment: I don't know how you're expected to write Python without learning any Python.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yeah, I don't know either. They expect us to learn it in our free time on our own. I've been doing lots of reading tutorials and using my Lynda account...

Comment: Do you know about lists?

Comment: @MadPhysicist No I do not but I will look into it

Comment: @Arman do you really think creating a class is necessary for storing an (x, y) pairing? A namedtuple would be more than sufficient, without the overhead of needing to define and create a class.

Comment: I mean I understand teaching object-oriented design, but shouldn't we also be teaching when it's useful, and when it's not. Even a dict would be more than sufficient for this.

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi , because each area has some walls and windows and each of them have width and heights , I think class would be great here , but I am agree dictionary is good too , but the concept of class is more helpful

Comment: @Arman ah, I didn't see the window and door part. Yes, I agree then that a class is ideal.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what class are you taking? We'd like to recommend people avoid the heck out of this class because it's terrible.

Comment: @WayneWerner lol the class is called "Foundations of Software Design". I think it's weird that it doesn't teach Python and we are expected to learn it on our own. I'm in week three of the class so apparently I was supposed to learn Python in under two weeks... :/

Comment: @Amerilys That seems super odd to have a class like that *not* have programming of some sort as a prerequisite. If  you have time I highly recomend going through the [official Python tutorial]( https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) as fast as you can. You might be able to get through it in a couple of hours for a couple days. Understanding all of that information should help you out with your class tremendously. Otherwise you'll probably find yourself falling further and further behind during a class, at least if it starts out like this. Out of curiosity, did this flowchart come from the class?

Comment: @WayneWerner No, I made the flowchart myself. We were given three different ideas for programs. I chose the "program to calculate the area of a room in order to purchase cans of paint". The first two weeks our assignments focused around flow charts for software design and this is the flowchart I came up with. Everything up until now was all in pseudo code and flowcharts. I like to think I'm pretty good at making flowcharts although I'm sure you are probably about to burst that bubble. Lol

Comment: @Amerilys It's not the *worst*, and given your inexperience, it's fine. Though it's less of a problem with the flowchart itself and more the underlying algorithm. Mainly your idea of having the doors and walls and things in the project name. I mean you certainly can do something like that, but converting that to code, especially as a beginner is pretty difficult. You'd be a lot better off if you just take the project name, then ask for dimensions of the walls and if they give you empty input there are no more walls. The same for ceilings, doors, and windows.

Comment: @WayneWerner which was my concern that I made it too difficult for myself. My instructor seemed really impressed by my flowchart though, so either all the other students suck or he thinks I'm about to knock it out of the park... I really appreciate you sharing the tutorial page. I'm definitely going to go through it more than a couple times over the next few weeks. This class is only for another two and a half weeks because it's half term class. Hopefully I can pull a rabbit out of a hat! If there is any other pointer please don't hesitate to share them with me. I always appreciate advice/help

Comment: I've updated my answer - if you can adjust your flowchart still, do that. You also may consider subscribing to the Python tutor list (just search, there's a mailing list you can sign up for). SO is really a site geared towards *professionals*. Which isn't to say that beginners aren't welcome, just that SO isn't designed for more intensive one-on-one help that you could really use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list or a tuple to store your walls ceiling etc. then its a matter of running a For loop to do the calculation. You may also want to use a dictionary if you want to call the items by name.

You can create Wall1, Wall2 etc using a simple string addition and put that in the dictionary rather than creating variables for each element.

If you clarify how you gonna accept the user input for all 57 walls etc. we can answer more accurately.

Comment: you say 'John wants to calculate how much paint he needs for a whole house and has 57 walls with various sizes of each wall'. So do you have to get all 57 walls sizes at once? or do you only need one wall at a time. Like lets say you let the user input the width, height and the type (wall, ceiling etc) then you output the calculated area and may be some type specific information?

Comment: @Amerilys do you have any prior programming knowledge at all in any language?

Comment: they would input the information for each wall one at a time. So it would ask how many walls do you have, so it knows a predetermined amount. Say it's six, it then prompts the user to input length and height for WALL1. Say I put in 13 length and 9 height. It should either do the calculation there and attached the result to WALL1 or hold the information to be calculated later. And I'm going with calculate now and hold the information to be called later. I'm taking an introductory class to HTML and CSS right now and I've messed around with some things prior but I've never learned.

Answer (score 0):

After our discussion in the comments, it appears that your real problem comes from [not really understanding the relative difficulty of things yet](https://xkcd.com/1425/). In large part that's because you don't really understand programming yet, you've just been making flowcharts in your class. There's a fair difference between flowcharts and programming, since with a flowchart you can just put `something magic happens`.

My first recommendation is to check out the Python style guide, called [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).
Most Python developers stick to this, and it will make your life easier when trying to communicate with us.

Next, you want to adjust your expectations. Trying to parse out a bunch of values from something like:

```
Wall 1 3x4 Wall 2 5x9 Wall 3 9x9 Door 1 2x6.5 Door 2 2x6.5
```

You *can* do it, but as a beginning developer it's a bit overwhelming. If you know regular expressions it's pretty trivial, but you don't, and they're not a beginning topic. Just remember the popular saying:

> Developers see a problem and say, "Ah, I know, I'll use regular expressions!" Now they have two problems.

Most of the time they're the wrong thing, but occasionally they're the right thing. But as a beginner, they're not the right thing.

Instead, you should aim for something like this:

- get the project name
- ask the user for wall sizes. When they input an empty/blank string, that's the last wall size
- ask the user for ceiling sizes (though you could include this in the wall sizes, no **need** to have them different). When they input an empty/blank string there are no more ceilings.
- ask the user for the door sizes. Same thing about empty strings.
- ask the user for window sizes. The same thing applies for ceiling vs walls.
- combine the wall/ceiling sizes and subtract (door sizes + window sizes)

You can store the sizes in lists, e.g. `walls = [[3, 4], [5, 9], [9, 9]]`. Dealing with lists is something that you can learn in the Python tutorial, or many other tutorials on the Internet.

You can iterate (loop) over your lists and write that information to a file, if that's something that you want to do. Tutorials will also cover that.

If you take the above approach, you'll find that your project is *much* easier to complete. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using pandas data frames to store each instance of Wall, Window and Ceiling? Then you multiply your columns `Width` by `Length` and store it in the column `Surface`.

Then you can simply use the `groupby`[function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) to get your totals and add up the results, or simply sum the `Surface`columns.

Comment: The user is just learning how to ride a bicycle, and you want to put a BMW M3 in front of him/her with pandas and the concept of dataframes?

Comment: I come from R and use spreadsheet a lot, so I must admit I have a harder time not using them. Might be the accountant in me, but I get a better grasp on my data when they're in a matrix like object.

Comment: If you read the flowchart the OP posted it's clearly not what the exercise is after.